# Custom ckeditor.styles.js possible to specify for any/all elements?

Tags: wysiwyg

In the ckeditor.styles.js can you leave the element blank or specify multiple elements in a single line? Ex. if the class .red could apply to any element, do I actually have to write out a line for every possible element?

```
{ name : 'Red' , element : 'p', attributes  : { 'class' : 'red' } },
{ name : 'Red' , element : 'h1', attributes  : { 'class' : 'red' } },
{ name : 'Red' , element : 'h2', attributes  : { 'class' : 'red' } },
```

etc...

Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 5):

I also searched for a way to specify multiple elements for one style - and it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. I was successful with specifying multiple elements as an array:

```
{ name: 'Red', element : ['h1', 'h2', 'p'], attributes: { 'class': 'red' } }
```

This works for me in CKEditor 4.2.1.

Comment: Although, this seems to work, it breaks the active state of the select.  When you choose an option, it doesn't show as active.  I had to separate the elements into their own hash.  In addition, I couldn't use the same name for multiple styles, I had to add an extra space to the names to make them unique.